# Call to a member function setTimezone() on a non-object returns error sometimes

Tags: php

Just so you know, I have looked at other questions and answers on this but haven't got a satisfactory result yet.

On the remote server I get the error "Call to a member function setTimezone() on a non-object" but not locally or on another server. The remote server is using php 5.4 and so it cant be a version problem. Also, if I dump new DateTimeZone('UTC') on the remote I get an empty object, but not locally.

Here are some dumps:

```
$testdate = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
var_dump($testdate); 

//On local dev: 
object(DateTimeZone)#248 (2) { ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }

//On remote server: 
object(DateTimeZone)#285 (0) { }
```

Please help.

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904376/php-timezone-returns-empty-array

Comment: That cannot be the answer because on one server the php version is 5.6.16.